# Cypress.io can't find the specs when wrapping with nodejs

Tags: node.js, cypress

I am trying to add a REST API on top of Cypress.io to mimic the Appium framework. I can run the test from the console, but when I try to run the spec with an http request cypress can't find the test. I've tried to add a bunch of different path settings in `cypress.json` located in the root folder of the project but no luck so far.

Here is a small example server of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
import express from 'express';
import cypress from 'cypress';

const app = express();
const PORT = 5000;

app.get('/cypress/v1/run/:specName', (req, res) => {
  cypress.run({
    spec: req.params.specName})
    .then(results => {
      res.status(200).send({
      status: results.totalFailed,
      result: results 
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)
});
```

Whatever I send in I get following error:
Request: `curl -v http://localhost:5000/cypress/v1/run/test.js`
Response: `{"result":{"failures":1,"message":"Could not find Cypress test run results"}}`

Log:

```
Can't run because no spec files were found.
We searched for any files matching this glob pattern:
test.js
```

So my question is, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Cypress seems to be *extremely* sensitive to configuration and is somewhat not logic. I changed the config file to following and specs are found:

```
{
  "projectId": "xyz123",
  "integrationFolder": "cypress/integration",
  "testFiles": "**/*.*"
}
```

I still have to specify the test as `cypress/integration/test.js`, otherwise Cypress will not find it.